# CROSS APPLY usage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

I might not understand the full usage of **CROSS APPLY**, so I hope someone can help me solve this.

The tables look like this:

```
MARK                  STAFF_RESOURCE     PLACING
----                  --------------     -------
ACCOUNT_DAY           EMPLOYNO           RES_ID
MARK_TIME             RES_ID             PLAC_ID
MARK_TYPE
PLAC_ID
```

The **MARK**-table has data like this:

```
ACCOUNT_DAY  MARK_TIME                  MARK_TYPE   PLAC_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-05   2015-02-05 13:02:01.029    1           5
2015-02-05   2015-02-05 18:32:21:744    2           5
2015-02-06   2015-02-06 09:02:01.029    1           5
2015-02-06   2015-02-06 14:32:21:744    2           5
```

The result I would like if doing a range selection on **ACCOUNT_DAY** (for instance february), looks like - this joining the tables by the **IDs**:

```
EMPLOYNO   ACCOUNT_DAY   MARK_TIME (1)              MARK_TIME (2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03064      2015-02-05    2015-02-05 13:02:01.029    2015-02-05 18:32:21:744
03064      2015-02-06    2015-02-06 09:02:01.029    2015-02-06 14:32:21:744
```

When using the code below the **MARK_TIME**-fields shows wrong data. Must I use a **JOIN** somewhere to get it right?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT stf.EMPLOYNO, A.ACCOUNT_DAY, sta.MARK_TIME, stp.MARK_TIME
FROM SYSADM.STAFF_RESOURCE AS stf  
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT PLAC_ID
FROM SYSADM.PLACING AS plc
WHERE stf.RES_ID = plc.RES_ID
)C
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT mrk.ACCOUNT_DAY, mrk.PLAC_ID
    FROM SYSADM.MARK AS mrk
    WHERE mrk.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID AND (mrk.ACCOUNT_DAY >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-01', 102)) AND (mrk.ACCOUNT_DAY < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-28', 102))
) A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MARK_TIME
    FROM SYSADM.MARK AS sta 
    WHERE (MARKTYPE = '1') AND (sta.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID) AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY <= '2015-02-01 23:59:59.999')
) sta 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MARK_TIME
    FROM SYSADM.MARK AS stp 
    WHERE (MARKTYPE = '2') AND (stp.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID) AND (stp.MARK_TIME >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND (stp.MARK_TIME <= '2015-02-01 23:59:59.999')
) stp
```

Comment: This might interest you: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `CROSS APPLY` but I imagine it to be used the other way around. If `CROSS APPLY` is not a requirement you can do it like:

```
select EMPLOYNO
     , ACCOUNT_DAY
     , MAX(case when MARK_TYPE = 1 
                then MARK_TIME 
           end) as MARK1
     , MAX(case when MARK_TYPE = 2 
                then MARK_TIME 
           end) as MARK2
from MARK m
join PLACING as p
    on m.PLAC_ID = p.PLAC_ID
join STAFF_RESOURCE s
    on p.RES_ID = s.RES_ID
group by EMPLOYNO
       , ACCOUNT_DAY
```

Comment: Thank you Lennart!
I think your solution will work just fine for me. I did some adjustments and it looks promising! :)